# How to add splash screen in ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-cli

[image]

ionic info:

ionic cordova resources:

[image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code / commands / error messages as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: It seems CloudFlare down.You need to wait for a while.

Comment: CLI **ionic resources** were renamed so will use on **ionic Cordova resources**

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can see in [this Github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2447):

> Cloudflare is used as a CDN in front of the API that generates the
>   resources for you. Seems Cloudflare somehow decided you (your IP
>   address) are/were "bad" and blocked your requests. If this happens in
>   the browser they show a Captcha for you to solve to prove you are
>   "good", but of course you can't do that on the command line.

So in order to solve this, please try to open this URL manually in your browser: `https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload`

It will probably show a Captcha or something. If the output is

```
{
  Error: "invalid request: GET",
  Width: 0,
  Height: 0,
  Type: "",
  Vector: false
}
```

You should try again `ionic cordova resources` on the command line, and the request should go through without problem.

Comment: still does not work. I am curious as to why I might get blocked in the first place.